# How do data types ensure portability/platform independence?

Tags: c, types, binary

From Modern C, Jens Gustedt (Chapter 5, Page 52):

> The data of a program execution consists of all the assembled values of all objects at
> a given moment. The state of the program execution is determined by:
>
> • The executable
>
> • The current point of execution
>
> • The data
>
> • Outside intervention, such as IO from the user
>
> If we abstract from the last point, an executable that runs with the same data from the
> same point of execution must give the same result. But since C programs should be portable
> between systems, we want more than that. We don’t want the result of a computation to
> depend on the executable (which is platform specific) but ideally to depend only on the
> program specification itself. **An important step to achieve this platform independence is
> the concept of types.**

Question 1: "An important step to achieve this platform independence is
the concept of types". How does this work? I'll be grateful if this can explained with an example as well.

Question 2: When compiler converts a value, take the integer constant 25, to binary, does the 'machine' realise or know that the binary code represents the value 25 (because without any context it may represent a character), or is the machine's only job to manipulate those bits and bytes and its left to us/compiler to infer the input as well as the output?

Comment: When you quote a source, cite the source. Give the author, title, edition, and page or chapter-section-subsection information at least.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil my bad, edited the answer and mentioned the source.

Comment: I am inclined to think that the sentence you have called out is a lead-in to a discussion of the very topic you have asked about.  So what does your source have to say about it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger — Section 5.1 of the book is about the Abstract State Machine.  The quote comes from sub-section 5.1.1 Values; sub-section 5.1.2 is about Types (and there are other sub-sections in 5.1).  Section 5.2 is about Basic Types.

Comment: Ok, @JonathanLeffler, that reinforces my inference.  The point is that the OP seems to be ignoring their source's answer to the question.  That's the first and best place for them to look.  If they don't understand what Jens has to say about it, then that should be part of the question they pose here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger — I agree.  Sub-section 5.1.2 is quite short; section 5.2 is longer; sections 5.3 through 5.7 discuss features of basic types; chapter 6 is on "Derived data types", and chapter 11 is on "Pointers" specifically (though pointers are certainly used in the interim).  So, "**read on**" is valid advice.